# Locking a SQL Server Database with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I'm wanting extra security for a particular point in my web app. So I want to lock the database (SQL Server 2005). Any suggestions or is this even necessary with SQL Server?

**Edit on question:**

The query is failing silently with no errors messages logged, and does not occur inside of a transaction.

**Final Solution:**

I never was able to solve the problem, however what I wound up doing was switching to MySQL and using a transactional level query here. This was not the main or even a primary reason to switch. I had been having problems with SQL Server and it allowed me to have our CMS and various other tools all running on the same database. Previous we had a SQL Server and a MySQL database running to run our site. The port was a bit on the time consuming however in the long run I feel it will work much better for the site and the business.

Comment: >didn't insert when two people were trying to insert at once. What is the error message you recieve on failure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose you have three options.

1. Set user permissions so that user x can only read from the database.
2. Set the database into single user mode so only one connection can access it

   sp_dboption 'myDataBaseName', single, true
3. Set the database to readonly

   sp_dboption 'myDataBaseName', read only, true

Answer (score 1):

I never was able to solve the problem, however what I wound up doing was switching to MySQL and using a transactional level query here. This was not the main or even a primary reason to switch. I had been having problems with MSSQL and it allowed me to have our CMS and various other tools all running on the same database. Previous we had a MSSQL and a MySQL database running to run our site. The port was a bit on the time consuming however in the long run I feel it will work much better for the site and the business.